# Angular 2 - How to access a service dependency in a unit test

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular2-services

I have the following Angular service which depends on `AngularFire`:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) { }

  // more code here
}
```

I'm unit testing this service with the following setup:

```ts
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ AngularFireModule.initializeApp(MY_FIREBASE_CONFIG) ],
  providers: [ FirebaseService ]
});
const firebaseService = TestBed.get(FirebaseService);
```

I can then do assertions on the service's methods such as:

```ts
// This works great
expect(firebaseService.callFoo()).toEqual('foo');
```

My question is how do I get a hold of the `AngularFire` instance that's injected in the constructor of `FirebaseService`? (`TestBed.get(AngularFire)` does not work; also, I don't have a component so I can't use the component's injector)

Site note: I know I should mock the backend for unit tests but it's not the point of the question here.

Comment: Not sure why `TestBed.get(FirebaseService)` doesn't work. What does happen there? Would `TestBed.get(FirebaseService)['af']` work then? And yes, usually this won't be a problem, because in unit tests all units but tested one are supposed to be mocked.

Comment: `TestBed.get(FirebaseService)` does work, it's `TestBed.get(AngularFire)` that doesn't. I suspect because `AngularFire` is not explicitly listed in the TestBed's providers (since it is provided by AngularFireModule).

Comment: But your comment made me realize if I inject `AngularFire` with `constructor(public af: AngularFire)` (vs `private)` it should be accessible as a service property. Thanks!